# Troubleshooting format of JSON get request

Tags: python, json, pandas, get, request

I'm running into an issue with trying to convert a get request response into my desired format. The structure of the JSON response is a little more complicated and I'm having trouble with getting it into the right format.

Here's my code for converting the json script into a pandas dataframe:

```
data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(resp_isrc.json())
data.head()
```

This is JSON structure that I am getting is below:

```
{"country":"US",
 "artist_name":"Frank Ocean",
 "title_name":"Provider",
 "release_date":"2017-08-25",
 "core_genre":"R&B/Hip-Hop",
 "metrics":[{"name":"ISRC w/SES On-Demand",
             "value":[{"name":"tp","value":2810},
                      {"name":"lp","value":2450},
                      {"name":"ytd","value":2740},
                      {"name":"atd","value":554267}]},
```

Comment: what data you need from Json file in witch columns?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi I'm trying to get the "tp" and "lp" values under "Streaming On-Demand Audio" in their own columns

Comment: You probably need to flatten the json before popping it into the dataframe. Simple things like change list of dictionaries into a dictionary. For example, `{"ISRC w/SES On-Demand":{"tp":2810, "lp":2450, "ytd":2740, "atd":554267},...}`.

Comment: @Tim so I tried flattening the json by doing this df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(resp_isrc) but the format doesn't appear to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of preprocessing may be needed to achieve what you want. This is fairly typical for json results from requests. In some cases a more general approach may be used. But here, since the structure is fairly simple, metrics can be flattened fairly easily.

```
def flatten2df(resp_isrc, df=None):
    metrics = resp_isrc.pop('metrics')
    flattened_json = []
    for item in metrics:
        metric = item['name']
        values = item['value']
        new_entry = {entry['name']: entry['value'] for entry in values}
        new_entry.update({'metric': metric})
        new_entry.update(resp_isrc)
        flattened_json.append(new_entry)
    new_df = pandas.DataFrame(flattened_json)
    if df is None:
        return new_df
    return df.append(new_df, ignore_index=True)
```

If there are multiple requests, you can loop it over

```
df = pandas.DataFrame()

for i in lst:
    response = requests.get(...)
    df = flatten2df(response.json(), df)
```

---

### Faster:

Appends all flattened results to a list first and then input into dataframe.

```
def flatten2list(resp_isrc, flattened_json):
    metrics = resp_isrc.pop('metrics')
    for item in metrics:
        metric = item['name']
        values = item['value']
        new_entry = {entry['name']: entry['value'] for entry in values}
        new_entry.update({'metric': metric})
        new_entry.update(resp_isrc)
        flattened_json.append(new_entry)
```

If there are multiple requests, you can loop it over

```
results = []

for i in lst:
    response = requests.get(...)
    flatten2list(response.json(), results)

df = pandas.DataFrame(results)
```

Comment: Hey Tim! thanks for the help here. So does 'metrics = resp_isrc.pop(metrics)'  parse 'metrics' from the rest of the json? I'm getting AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'pop'

Comment: You might need resp_isrc=resp_isrc.json() first. Pop is a dictionary method that remove and returns the key value pair from the dictionary.

Comment: Awesome this worked! one last thing though, would you know how to transpose the 'name; column so that tp, lp, ytd, and atd  are their own columns with their corresponding values?

Comment: Updated answer, now should give you the columns

Comment: Hey Tim, this worked perfectly! Although, now with adding in multiple json requests, the df only returns data for the very last request. Not sure if it's possible, but any ideas on how I can output multiple requests into the df?

Comment: I believe it is a list of dictionaries. I've included an example photo of what the output looks like

Comment: This was working initially, but now for some reason it is taking a really long time to process the loop over multiple requests...to the point where I have to interrupt kernel.

Comment: Was only testing with three requests, which i would assume should be able to handle no problem.

Comment: If all three responses are similar to the one in your post, it shouldn't take long at all (the operation shouldn't take much memory either). One thing could be that the requests are taking a long time. One thing to do is to get all the responses in a list and then process each response later. Does the faster solution help?

Answer (score 1):

Here how you can extract `name, ip lp` data from json dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd

data = []
for item in raw_data.get('metrics'):
    tp = 0
    lp = 0
    for name in item.get('value'):
        if 'tp' in name.values():
            tp = name.get('value')
        if 'lp' in name.values():
            lp = name.get('value')
    data.append([item.get('name'), tp, lp])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name', 'ip', 'lp'])
```

**Output:**

```
                         name      ip      lp
0        ISRC w/SES On-Demand    2810    2450
1  ISRC w/SES On-Demand Audio    2735    2384
2              Digital Tracks      21      19
3   Streaming On-Demand Total  395705  348276
4   Streaming On-Demand Audio  367707  323399
5   Streaming On-Demand Video   27998   24877
6  Streaming Programmed Total     187     153
```

Comment: so when I run this, I end up getting this AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'. As mentioned in the comments above, I'd have to "flatten" the JSON before throwing it into a df, so perhaps this is why we're getting this error?

Comment: @KirklandShawty `raw_data` is directed to the Jonson that you posted. Error is because you data is in list of dictionary..